# Neo4j/Cypher : Counting the number of Graphs in a DB or match result

Tags: graph, neo4j, count, cypher, match

As a Graph DB is a collection of Graphs (1-N), is there a simple way to return the number of Graphs? There are many possibilities to count nodes, properties and relationships, but don't seem to be able to find something on counting Graphs itself, and metadata on  those Graphs. Eg returning that there are 5 Graphs of 10 nodes and 15 relationships and 5 Graphs of 5 nodes and 7 relationships ... would be a table if there are many Graphs. On a second level, the same counting on a match result - that is, match some condition, and count the number of Graphs of which the resulting nodes are part of.

[Adding extras]
[screendump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDsOZ.jpg) This is the result of a cypher yielding three distinct Graphs. The easiest one is the one at the bottom right, which is 5 nodes with 4 relationships.
What I would like to get returned is the number 3 (primary goal), as there are 3 Graphs, and for each of them (secondary goal) the number of nodes and relationships contained within them.
Hope this clarifies more.

Comment: You are probably wanting to use the weakly connected component algorithm

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
CALL algo.unionFind.stream() YIELD nodeId, setId
RETURN DISTINCT setId, COUNT(DISTINCT nodeId) AS nodesCount
ORDER BY nodesCount DESC LIMIT 100
;
```